# Converting a list of objects into a record type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a type-safe function which takes in a list of objects of shape `{ key: Key, test: boolean }` and returns an object of shape `{ [name: Key]: Type }`. *(`Key` should be just `extends string`)*. `Type` should be `number` if the `test` property for the given object is `true` and `string` if it's `false`.

Example:

```
const r = f([
    { key: 'foo', test: true },
    { key: 'bar', test: false }
]);

// `typeof r` should be `{ 'foo': number, 'bar': string }`
```

This is how far I can get and I'm not sure what to do afterwards.

```
function f<T extends string>(xs: { name: T, key: boolean }[]): ??? {
    // ...
}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is achievable. Full solution:

```
// type represents the input array element
type KeyTest = { key: string, test: boolean };

// type process input array into wanted object
type Result<T extends KeyTest[]
    ,_Keys extends string = {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends KeyTest ? T[K]['key'] : never
    }[keyof T & number]> = {
    [K in _Keys]: {
            [I in keyof T]:
            T[I] extends KeyTest ? T[I]['key'] extends K
            ? true extends T[I]['test'] ? number : string
            : never
            : never
    }[keyof T & number]
} 

// type level Result type check
type Test = Result<[
    { key: 'foo', test: true },
    { key: 'bar', test: false }
]>

declare function f<T extends Array<KT>
, KT extends {key: Key, test: Test}
, Key extends string
, Test extends boolean>(...xs: T): Result<T>

// example usage:    
const r = f({ key: 'foo', test: true },  { key: 'bar', test: false });
type X = typeof r;

// working with existing arrays
const arr = [
    { key: 'foo', test: true },
    { key: 'bar', test: false }
] as const; // here as const because type will be infered as an array
const r2 = f(...arr);
type X2 = typeof r2;
```

[The Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-0gMkU1icmlEG6CujYFlQTJsjnB1A8vkCgSFkSiSTQAAaHm3NRIm-FkoA7qwSLg-lBT2RgAALWJkVDX9nO+yd7toN8eIkRmeknOI5jiGk6MsygHzuyIHLgqq6CsKUDcHoXYUKgn5oWgJAAEweP2ubZm+G6YlIO64ZgB6hDhm5AA)

Unfortunately in order to get proper type narrowing I needed to change the function input from single Array argument to list of arguments. I hope it is not an issue for you. The real difference is we need to use `...` before passing an array. It was done because by default TS treats array types as arrays not as tuples.

Explanation of the `Result`type:

- `_Keys` - these are all `key` property types gathered from the tuple
- `[K in _Keys]` - we are looping through all keys gathered from the tuple
- `[I in keyof T]` - we again go through original tuple, its like for inside for
- `T[I]['key'] extends K ? true extends T[I]['test'] ? number : string` - so we are inside second for and there we check if tuple element has `key` exact current key we have in our map type, if so we check if `test` is true, if so we assign to it `number` if not `string`